# Laravel managing Personal Access Tokens

Tags: laravel, token, laravel-passport

I'm following [Laravel documentation to "Managing Personal Access Tokens"](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens)

I created a TestController try to create a personal access token.

```
  public function getToken()
    {

      $user = \App\User::find(1);
      // Creating a token without scopes...
      $token = $user->createToken('3page')->accessToken;
      dd($token);

    }
```

I can get the `$user` but get error when createToken

```
{
    "message": "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/test/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
    "line": 98,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/vagrant/code/test/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php",
            "line": 98,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Please advice!

Comment: The line it's failing on is trying to get the id of a the personal access client, did you follow the first two steps correctly?

Comment: did you run `php artisan passport:install`?

Comment: @AlecJoy Yes, I did.

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand I did

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `php artisan passport:client --personal` command?

You have to set the `--personal` flag in order to use your code.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#creating-a-personal-access-client